# how are these probability rules derived?

Tags: probability

I was reading a note and got to the following equations. Not sure how they are derived.
$$\Pr(\overline{E_t} \cap · · · \cap E_0) = \Pr(E_{t−1} \cap · · · \cap E_0)−\Pr(E_t \cap · · · \cap E_0)$$
and
$$Pr (E_{t−1} \cap · · · \cap E_0) − Pr (E_t \cap · · · \cap E_0)
= Pr(E_{t−1}) − Pr(E_t) −
[
Pr(E_{t−1}\cap \overline{E_{t−2} \cap · · · \cap E_0})
−Pr(E_t \cap\overline{E_{t−1} \cap · · · \cap E_0})
]$$
Any idea?

Comment: How are the events, $\{E_k\}$, defined ?  And are you sure you copied the terms correctly ?  ( Look at the LHS and last term on the RHS of the first equation. Why are they the same?)

Comment: I corrected a mistake in the first eq. The events are not independent. Yes, they are correctly copied. The second equation is used to approximate the first one. However, both seem strange. They are published in a journal paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.   The first equation is of the form: $\Pr(\overline A\cap B) = \Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

The probability event $B$ happens but event $A$ does not, is equal to the probability that $B$ happens minus the probability that both events $A$ and $B$ happen.

This is more often written: $\Pr(B)=\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(\overline A\cap B)$ which is the **Law of Total Probability**.

When we substitute $A=E_t$ and $B=(E_{t-1}\cap\cdots\cap E_0)$ we obtain your formula:

$$\Pr(\overline {E_t}\cap E_{t-1}\cap\cdots\cap E_0) ~=~ \Pr(E_{t-1}\cap\cdots\cap E_0)-\Pr(E_t\cap E_{t-1}\cap\cdots\cap E_0)$$

---

Similarly the other equation is of the form:
$$\begin{align}\Pr (B\cap C) − \Pr (A\cap B\cap C) 
&= \Pr(B)-\Pr(B\cap \overline C)-\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)
\\[1ex] & = \Pr(B)-\Pr(B\cap \overline C)-\Pr(A)+\Pr(A\cap\overline{B\cap C})
\\[1ex] & = \Pr(B)-\Pr(A)-\big(\Pr(B\cap \overline C)-\Pr(A\cap\overline{B\cap C})\big)
\end{align}$$

Where $A=E_t, B=E_{t-1}, C=E_{t-2}\cap\cdots\cap E_0$ we obtain:

$$\begin{align} & \Pr (E_{t-1}\cap \cdots\cap E_0) − \Pr (E_t\cap\cdots\cap E_0) 
\\[0.5ex] = & \Pr(E_{t-1})-\Pr(E_t) -\big(\Pr(E_{t-1}\cap \overline {E_{t-2}\cap\cdots\cap E_0})-\Pr(E_t\cap\overline{E_{t-1}\cap\cdots\cap E_0})\big)
\end{align}$$

Comment: can you give me a reference that I could refer to for more details and similar?